# Are items not on a list Implicitly or Explicitly not members of a group?

Tags: meaning

If someone is a position of authority makes a list they say is complete, are items NOT on the list implicitly or explicitly NOT members of the list?

Ex: if a person is NOT on a class roster, can they said to be implicitly or explicitly not a student in the class?

Comment: *explicit* means stated. The *implication* of being not listed on a class list is that they are not part of the class.  They would be explicitly excluded from the class if there were a list that said, "The following people are not in the class:  ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody says the list is complete and an item is not on the list, the implication from that circumstance alone is that the missing item is not a member of that category. Otherwise the list would not be truly [complete](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=complete&use1913=on), as there would be a part or element missing from the list. The list could be considered complete/[completed](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=completed&use1913=on) in the sense of [finish](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=finish&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on)/[finished](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=finished&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on) if work on it has stopped but it would not truly be so, since it is erroneous, not perfected and something technically could be added to it to continue the working process. You might say that such a person was "[left off [of the] list](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leave+off)"  as from this example:

---

> We left them off the guest list because of their behavior at our last party.

---

Regarding your specific example, it reminds me of an excerpt from Azumanga Daioh. I shall not spoil how the touching scene plays out but I do recall that Ayumu Kasuga dismayed over being unable to find her name on the same class roster boards as her friends, which could unfortunately distance her from them. I suppose a Japanese comic book has little to do with the English per-se but it does help to exemplify the implication certainly exists and is even cross-cultural.

Granted an [implication](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=implication&use1913=on) is not definitive and its very possible that somebody might be left off of the list by mistake, rather than purposefully. There may be certain other overriding circumstances that trump the list but without knowing those, the above considerations are most likely to apply.

---

> **Citations:**
>
> Single word Definitions: [Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary, 1913](http://www.bibliomania.com/2/3/257/frameset.html)
>
> leave off. (n.d.) The American Heritage Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs. (2005). Retrieved from The Free Dictionary by Farlex
>
> Azumanga Daioh Volume 2, Chapter 15 ([wikia link](http://azumanga.wikia.com/wiki/Azumanga_Daioh_Volume_2/Chapter_15) [*spoiler warning*])